# Define ckeditor add media library location

Tags: wysiwyg, media, theming

we're currently using ckeditor successfully, but when i go to add media from the library tab it loads up all media, we want to exclude profile images from this, is it possible to define the ckeditor library path, or would we really want to move the profile images to private directory

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Views Media Browser](https://drupal.org/project/views_media_browser) module

> This module adds a Views based Media browser to the site that allows filtering files based on fields attached to the various file types.